# Not able to see icons in android-4.2

Tags: css, sencha-touch-2, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am not able to see the icon in android-4.2 but can see in lower versions. Can anyone explain what is the issue? Here is the html body:

```
 <div class="ss-symbolicons-block ss-car" data-rel="test"></div>
```

You can find the sample icon here:
http://jsfiddle.net/72k8n/1/

It looks in Android-4.2.1 like:

[image]

And in Android-4.0.4 like:

[image]

We are using these files for displaying icons:

http://apps.innofied.com/sencha/anand/symbolset/ss-symbolicons-block.css

http://apps.innofied.com/sencha/anand/symbolset/ss-symbolicons-block.svg

http://apps.innofied.com/sencha/anand/symbolset/ss-symbolicons-block.ttf

http://apps.innofied.com/sencha/anand/symbolset/ss-symbolicons-block.woff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried adding `z-index : 1` to the parent container and that is working fine